# mapbox infoControl causes 'undefined is not a function' errors when used with .addInfo method

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, leaflet, mapbox

Anyone know what's up with mapbox.js's infoControl, and how can I implement it with `position` option and `.addInfo()` method without failing tests?

I'm having trouble with the infoControl in Mapbox 1.6.1 -- it's failing rake tests with 'undefined is not an object' or 'not a function'. Undocumented options like `position` still work with it. I'm using the other controls (eg zoom, layers) without the same problems.

My code:

```
class MyMap extends Backbone.View
  initialize: (@options) ->
    @map = L.mapbox.map(mapContainer, @options.mapboxMap, 
    zoomControl: false, 
    infoControl: false)
    @addControls()

  addControls: (map) ->
    L.mapbox.infoControl({ position: 'bottomleft' }).addInfo('Contains information from YZ.').addTo(@map)
    L.control.scale().addTo(@map)
    L.control.zoom(position: 'bottomleft').addTo(@map)
```

Throughout this, the info box still *works* fine on my map, there's no problem with it besides it failing these rake tests.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you're trying to use, or a link to a page. As-is, this is not debuggable.

Comment: @tmcw sure, code added.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're calling `@addControls()`, when you should be calling `@addControls(@map)` - `.addTo(undefined)` is being called, which is invalid.

Comment: hmm still fails those rake tests with the same error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'L.mapbox.infoControl()')`

Comment: Maybe your rake tests aren't including the mapbox.js library? Really there's no way to know from the outside.